# Running Totals by Month

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a row count of each table collected each day.  I am trying to make a query and ultimately put it in a report, that will give me the total rows per table 6,5,4,3,2, and 1 month ago.  Once I have those numbers I can calculate % change or make a graph out of it.  Right now this kind of works but stops working as I add more months back, and it just is a lot of repeating code.  Wondering if anyone has thought of a more efficient way to do this.

```
DECLARE @DT1 DATETIME,
        @DT2 DATETIME,
        @DT3 DATETIME,
        @DT4 DATETIME;

SELECT @DT1 = MAX(AnalysisDate)
FROM DBA_TableSpaceUsedHistory;
SELECT @DT2 = MAX(AnalysisDate)
FROM DBA_TableSpaceUsedHistory
WHERE AnalysisDate < DATEADD(hh, -23, @DT1);
SELECT @DT3 = MAX(AnalysisDate)
FROM DBA_TableSpaceUsedHistory
WHERE AnalysisDate < DATEADD(mm, -1, DATEADD(hh, 1, @DT1));
SELECT @DT4 = MAX(AnalysisDate)
FROM DBA_TableSpaceUsedHistory
WHERE AnalysisDate < DATEADD(mm, -3, DATEADD(hh, 1, @DT1));

-- SELECT @DT1, @DT2, @DT3

SELECT TOP 5
       t1.TableSchema,
       t1.TableName,
       FORMAT(t3.TableRows, '#,##0') [3 Months Value],
       FORMAT(t2.TableRows, '#,##0') [Day Old Value],
       FORMAT(t1.TableRows, '#,##0') [New Value],
       FORMAT((t1.TableRows - t2.TableRows), '#,##0') [1 Day Difference],
       CASE WHEN t2.TotalSpaceKB > 0 THEN FORMAT((((t1.TableRows - t2.TableRows) / (t2.TableRows * 1.0)) * 100.0), '##0.00')
            ELSE '100'
       END AS '% Difference',
       FORMAT((t1.TableRows - t3.TableRows), '#,##0') [3 Month Difference],
       CASE WHEN t2.TotalSpaceKB > 0 THEN FORMAT((((t1.TableRows - t3.TableRows) / (t3.TableRows * 1.0)) * 100.0), '##0.00')
            ELSE '100'
       END AS '% Difference'
FROM DBA_TableSpaceUsedHistory t1
    INNER JOIN DBA_TableSpaceUsedHistory t2
        ON t1.TableSchema = t2.TableSchema
           AND t1.TableName = t2.TableName
    INNER JOIN DBA_TableSpaceUsedHistory t3
        ON t1.TableSchema = t3.TableSchema
           AND t1.TableName = t3.TableName
WHERE t1.AnalysisDate = @DT1
      AND t2.AnalysisDate = @DT2
      AND t1.AnalysisDate = @DT1
      AND t3.AnalysisDate = @DT4
ORDER BY t1.TableRows - t2.TableRows DESC;

SELECT *
FROM DBA_TableSpaceUsedHistory;
```

The result is looking like this and this is the kind of the idea but I want to go back a few more months.  Thanks for any tips!!

[image]

Comment: If you want a running total, have you considered using a windowed aggregate?

Comment: Nope - But I'll Google it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example using [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) window functions that should help get you started.

```sql
SELECT TableSchema, TableName, TableRows AS NewValue,
LastMonthValue, TwoMonthsValue, ThreeMonthsValue
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    -- window functions to select previous rows. I've included three,
    -- just add however many needed depending on how far you want to go back
    LAG(TableRows,1) OVER (PARTITION BY TableSchema, TableName ORDER BY AnalysisDate) AS LastMonthValue,
    LAG(TableRows,2) OVER (PARTITION BY TableSchema, TableName ORDER BY AnalysisDate) AS TwoMonthsValue,
    LAG(TableRows,3) OVER (PARTITION BY TableSchema, TableName ORDER BY AnalysisDate) AS ThreeMonthsValue,
    -- The RowNum (below) together with the final WHERE clause
    -- means you always get the row with the latest AnalysisDate per partition,
    -- The LAGs allow you to see the older rows as far back as desired
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableSchema, TableName ORDER BY AnalysisDate DESC) AS RowNum
  FROM (
    -- sample data (filtered or grouped as monthly)
    -- you could perhaps do some other join if you need a total for yesterday included
    SELECT 'dbo', 'Session', 10, '2022-01-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dbo', 'Session', 20, '2022-02-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dbo', 'Session', 30, '2022-03-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dbo', 'Session', 40, '2022-04-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dbo', 'UploadRates', 100, '2022-01-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dbo', 'UploadRates', 200, '2022-02-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dbo', 'UploadRates', 300, '2022-03-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dbo', 'UploadRates', 400, '2022-04-01'
  ) AS DBA_TableSpaceUsedHistory (TableSchema, TableName, TableRows, AnalysisDate)
) AS t
WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Output:

| TableSchema | TableName | NewValue | LastMonthValue | TwoMonthsValue | ThreeMonthsValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dbo | Session | 40 | 30 | 20 | 10 |
| dbo | UploadRates | 400 | 300 | 200 | 100 |

Comment: This was helpful learning more about these window functions but I was unable to get it to run.  However did get this to run, just need to figure out how to add the different counts per month in the same row vs down the column.

Comment: SELECT
 x.AnalysisDate,
 x.TableSchema + x.TableName AS TableName,
 x.TableRows,
 x.rownumber
 FROM (
    SELECT 
     AnalysisDate,
     TableSchema, 
     TableName, 
     TableRows,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableSchema, TableName, MONTH(AnalysisDate) ORDER BY AnalysisDate DESC) rownumber
     FROM dbo.DBA_TableSpaceUsedHistory ) x
WHERE x.rownumber = 1
AND x.TableName = 'Session'
ORDER BY x.AnalysisDate desc

Comment: @Lucas you can better help others help you if you update your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (a small sample of your raw data like what I generated from assumptions), and ideally provide a visual example of your desired output - in this case, a manually generated table showing what you want in each row / column, based on your sample data. At present it's difficult offer more assistance.

Comment: To clarify, your existing screencap is useful, though would be helpful to see more of the desired columns, especially based on the sample data.